# Prepopulating inlines based on the parent model in the Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I have two models, `Event` and `Series`, where each Event belongs to a Series. Most of the time, an Event's `start_time` is the same as its Series' `default_time`.

Here's a stripped down version of the models.

```
#models.py

class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default_time = models.TimeField()

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
```

I use inlines in the admin application, so that I can edit all the Events for a Series at once.

If a series has already been created, I want to prepopulate the `start_time` for each inline Event with the Series' `default_time`. So far, I have created a model admin form for Event, and used the `initial` option to prepopulate the time field with a fixed time.

```
#admin.py
...
import datetime

class OEventInlineAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_time = forms.TimeField(initial=datetime.time(18,30,00))
    class Meta:
        model = OEvent

class EventInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = EventInlineAdminForm
    model = Event

class SeriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EventInline,]
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Is it possible to extend the code, so that the initial value for the `start_time` field is the Series' `default_time`?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442040/pre-populate-an-inline-formset

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to close a function over a ModelAdmin:

```
def create_event_form(series):
    class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # You can use the outer function's 'series' here
    return EventForm
```

Here series will be the `series` instance.
Then in the inline admin class:

```
class EventInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Event
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            self.form = create_foo_form(obj)
        return super(EventInlineAdmin, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: This approach will enable you to pass your `series` object to the form where you can use it to set a default for your field.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the answer. Where do I hook the create_foo_form function into the Django admin?

Comment: Just create the function anywhere before your modeladmin class in the admin module.

Comment: Not able to access the series variable this way?