# Django Admin: How to 'prepopulate' inline foreign key field based on parent model

Tags: django, django-admin, inline

Some comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442040/pre-populate-an-inline-formset) indicate there is more straightforward and up-to-date solution. (I didn't find any)

(comments like: "Yes it's solved. Just pass the related instance in parameter, and it will prepopulate it..." makes me think it is easy now, but still I can't make it work)

The thing is that I want to send notice to some users which are involved in given event and selected by admin staff.
Staff-member is on the page of event, selects the event and saves it, than fk fields in inline should prepopulate with involved usernames. (and waiting to staff-member to check them or uncheck them to receive e-mail notice)

For usability reasons it's critical that this should take form of inline since there are allready lot of pages to go through to gather all necessary informations from staff.

Any ideas?

```
class When(models.Model):
    ...
    Date = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
    Nameofevent = models.ForeignKey(Event, to_field='Name') #the Event model gets then username from models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Role')
    ...
    def getteam(self):
        teamlist = self.Nameofevent.Roleinevent.all() # gathering users which are involved
        return teamlist
    getteamresult = property(getteam)

class Notice(models.Model): #this will go to the inline
    ...
    Who = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
    To_notice_or_not_to_notice = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

class NoticeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Notice
    extra = 9

class WhenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Date', ...)
    readonly_fields = ('getteamresult', ) #this is to make clear i have access to what i want and i can display it. prints out as [<User: someone>, <User: someoneelse>]
    inlines = [NoticeInline] #but i want the User objects to prepopulate foreign field here in inline model
admin.site.register(When,WhenAdmin)
```

Comment: Why not just solve it by creating a filter on the user model that filters all users who received (or haven't received) the notice? Then you could create an admin action that sends the notices.

Comment: The steps are: filter users which have something to do with given theater play. Than let staff to indicate which ones of them will receive notification for given reprise (event) - not all of them are necessary (the director for example is not attending all reprises). This operation is done while the staff is submitting all other information about this particular event.

Comment: That makes it a lot clearer. So why not solve it by having a many-to-many in Event linked to User? It can be either a widget like [filter_horizontal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) or an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models). You could then send notices to those users.

Comment: I was trying to reduce the problem for make the question clear but it's not that simple. User is not directly M-M to Event. There are quite lot of intermediate models like 'role', 'role name' etc. which take effect in relations. Theatre environment is quite complicated and sometimes even chaotic. I want to make it so easy as possible for non-technical staff to fill in all info I need for: e-mail noticing, web page generating, customized shedules for everyone involved, ... And now I'm so close to my holy grail;-)

Comment: Unless you explain exactly what you want, we can't really help you.

Comment: I want to 'prepopulate' inline foreign key field based on parent model, as stated above. i.e. pass in some way info from parent model to inline one and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe inlines are the the way to go for something like this. If the staff-member should be prompted to email users involved in the event, and needs control over which ones are actually notified, then you should use an intermediate view.

First, you need a form that will let you select users that belong to the event. Initially, we set the `users` field to just be all users, but in the form's `__init__` method we'll take the "event" kwarg and filter the field based on that.

```
class UserNotifyForm(forms.Form):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        event = kwargs.pop('event')
        super(UserNotifyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if event:
            self.fields['users'].queryset = event.users.all()
```

Second, you create a view on your `ModelAdmin`, that will behave just as a normal form view would:

```
def notify_users_view(self, request, object_id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=object_id)
    if len(request.POST):
        form = UserNotifyForm(request.POST, event=event)
        if form.is_valid():
            users = form.cleaned_data.get('users')
            # send email
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:yourapp_event_changelist'))
    else:
        form = UserNotifyForm(event=event)

    return render_to_response('path/to/form/template.html', {
        'event': event,
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You'll of course need to create template for this, but that's simple enough. The form is already set up to show a list of checkboxes, one for each user, so you have all the info you need there.

Third, tie this view into your `ModelAdmin`'s urls:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()

    info = (self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name)

    my_urls = patterns('',
        (r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/notify/$', self.notify_users_view, name='%s_%s_notify' % info)
    )
    return my_urls + urls
```

Fourth, override the `change_view` to redirect to this view after save:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    response = super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)
    if len(request.POST):
        info = (self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name)
        response['Location'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_notify', args=(object_id,))
    # Note: this will effectively negate the 'Save and Continue' and
    # 'Save and Add Another' buttons. You can conditionally check
    # for these based on the keys they add to request.POST and branch
    # accordingly to some other behavior you desire.
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get most of your answer, but definitely I have to put it one one page along with the 'When' model. Otherwise it would become a mess and it would result in usability disaster. Finaly, they wouldn't use it. And I believe it's possible, I have all info I need, just to connect it together... If the Django-way fails I have to make it with js (even if my js skills suck)