# How to set default values in TabularInline formset in Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

How to set first default rows/values in django admin's inline?

```
    class Employee(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(_('Username'), max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
        email = models.CharField(_('Email'), max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)

    class Details(models.Model):
        employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, verbose_name=_('Employee'), blank=False, null=False)
        label = models.CharField(_('Label'), max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
        value = models.CharField(_('Value'), max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)


    class DetailsFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.initial = [
{ 'label': 'first name'},  
{'label': 'last name'}, 
{'label': 'job',}]
            super(DetailsFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class DetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Details
        formset = DetailsFormset
        fieldsets = [
                ['', {'fields': ['employee', 'label', 'value']}]
        ]

    class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [DetailsInline]
```

but this row doesn't work

```
    self.initial = [
{ 'label': 'first name'},  
{'label': 'last name'}, 
{'label': 'job',}]
```

How do I set default values using django admin?

Comment: define `doesn't work`. What is the result ?

Comment: I wanted that the first default rows as firstname, lastname and job, but this can't define any default values

Comment: just want to mention, for me it was much easier to just set the default value on the _model_.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from django.utils.functional import curry

class DetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Details
    formset = DetailsFormset
    extra = 3

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        initial = []
        if request.method == "GET":
            initial.append({
                'label': 'first name',
            })
        formset = super(DetailsInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        formset.__init__ = curry(formset.__init__, initial=initial)
        return formset
```

From here: [Pre-populate an inline FormSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442040/pre-populate-an-inline-formset)

Comment: I wanted that the first default rows as firstname, lastname and job, but it sets always the same values

Comment: yes, I need to define three inline rows as default which are static

Comment: Ok I will try to test it in my app. If I solved it, I will post my answer

Comment: The initial values are shown in the add form, however when click save the values are not saved.
Whats the solution to this?

Comment: Worked for me in Django 2.2. In my case I only needed initial data on very new forms (no objects saved / linked), so I ended up modifying the the `if` condition to `if request.method == "GET" and (not obj or not obj.id):`. Also, if adding initial data is the only requirement, you don't need to mention `formset` explicitly under the class.

Answer (score 5):

If what you need is to define default values for the new forms that are created you can redefine the `empty_form` property of a `InlineFormSet`:

```
class MyDefaultFormSet(django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    @property
    def empty_form(self):
       form = super(MyDefaultFormSet, self).empty_form
       # you can access self.instance to get the model parent object
       form.fields['label'].initial = 'first name'
       # ...
       return form

 class DetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    formset = MyDefaultFormSet
```

Now, every time you add a new form it contains the initial data you provided it with. I've tested this on django 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many suggestions from Stackoverflow (Django=4.x), not working for me.
Here is what I did.

```
class MilestoneFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Milestone

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MilestoneFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.instance.pk: 
            self.initial = [
            {'stage': '1.Plan', 'description': 'Requirements gathering', },
            {'stage': '2.Define', 'description': 'Validate requirement', },
            ]

class MilestoneInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Milestone
    formset = MilestoneFormSet  

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        extra = 0  #default 0
        if not obj: #new create only
            extra = 2 #2 records defined in __init__
        return extra
```

I hope this works for everyone.

Comment: This works for me when dealing with `choices` in the form, but not working if I am trying to fill the fields using `foreignkey`.

Answer (score -2):

To provide a static default for all instances in the inline, I found a simpler solution that just sets it in a form:

```
class DetailsForm(django_forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['label'] = 'first_name'


class DetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = DetailsForm
    # ...
```

I think this doesn't work for the OP's particular case because each form has a different value for the `'label'` field, but I hope it can be useful for anyone coming to this page in the future.