# Files uploaded through a "multipart/form-data" form aren't stored anywhere

Tags: django

I've been struggling with this for some time and it makes me think that what I want to achieve is done differently in Django.

I have a model (`Album`) with the following definition:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    building_id = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField()
```

I have another model (`Photo`):

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    album_id = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="photos")
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
```

You can probably see where this is going: I want to be able to upload many photos at once when creating a photo album.

To access my `Album` data through Django admin, I register it:

```
@admin.register(models.Album)
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = forms.AlbumForm
```

And the associated form, which apparently **must** inherit from `ModelForm`:

```
class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ["building_id", "name", "photos"]

    building_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Building.objects.all())
    name = forms.CharField()
    photos = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple": True}))
```

After this setup, going to http://localhost:8000/admin/api/album/add offers me a form (with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`) where I can upload my files.

Pressing the `submit` button succesfully create the new `album`, but the uploaded photos are nowhere to be found (my `${MEDIA_ROOT}/photos` is still empty), and obviously no `Photo` model is created.

What would be the best "Django way" of doing it, and how could I achieve any of the following:

1. Whenever a new album is saved, recover the files from the `POST` request (if that's even a thing?), and store them before creating the associated `Photo` objects.
2. Create a custom view that would be used instead of the default one provided by the `ModelForm` my `AlbumForm` is inheriting from. I've tried this but it seems pretty hard, I seemingly can't plug any view to an url already owned by Django (like `"/admin/api/album/add"`) else it goes crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your views

Comment: If you are using class based view, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101507/using-formsets-for-my-fileupload-does-not-work-when-doing-an-update-class-based/65102164#65102164

Comment: @ha-neul: I'm not using any custom views, I'm just registering my model with the `@admin.register` annotation and specifying a form extending `ModelForm` as the default form (which seems to generate the create/update/delete views under the hood?)

Comment: @ha-neul: I'm taking a look, thank you.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your needs. You are trying to do this in admin only?

Comment: @ha-neul: Yes, this is correct. I see that in the link you shared there are some views defined, I'm strictly trying to get it working through the admin's web UI. The issue with my misunderstanding is that I don't even understand how these views integrate with Django admin, it seems that when using `@admin.register`, Django generates views for you

Comment: You need to use TabularInline formset for admin. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376874/how-to-set-default-values-in-tabularinline-formset-in-django-admin

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm taking a look

Comment: Okay, I managed to create an inline for my photos... But this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Doing this allows me to create many photos, but I have to upload them by hand, one by one. I want to be able to upload several them at once through a single `FileField`: `photos = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple": True}))`

Comment: Unfortunately Django does not allow you to save multiple files into a single filefield. In this case, you need to separate your form and model. Means your form will not come from modelform, just input. Then, In a single form input, upload multiple files, and save them one by one to your filefield.